# Запуск CMS из консоли PHP

Tags: php, cms, консоль, битрикс

Нужно запустить Битрикс в консоле PHP. Но, само собой, при запуске пути типа "/bitrix/header.php" и прочие, отсчитываются от корня файловой системы, а не сервера, и скрипт не запускается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как так изловчиться, чтобы PHP все пути правильно находил. Т.е. считал корневой директорию сайта. Или может есть какой-то специальный файл чтобы битрикс в консоле прогрузить?
Пример запуска:

> `$ php -f /var/www/mysite/index.php
> PHP Warning: require(/bitrix/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mysite/index.php on line 1`

ну и т.д.

Comment: Все гениально просто=) Спасибо, прокатило с DOCUMENT_ROOT !!!

Comment: Принимайте) Рад, что помогло, сам сейчас пытаюсь многодоменность настроить на 1 лицензию %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если устроит именно один конкретный файл - создайте, например, index2.php и заполните в нем массив $_SERVER ( `DOCUMENT_ROOT` и `HTTP_HOST` как минимум ), а потом сделайте `require 'index.php';`, может прокатить.

Не уверен, что сработает, сразу говорю.